# Sandbox Event Receiver Not Working on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers, sandbox-solution

I build an SharePoint 2013 Sandbox Event Receiver which works in my local on-prem dev environment.  However, when pushing it up to my SharePoint Online tenant it does not work nor even fire at all.

I can see the event receiver attaching and detaching from my list using the SharePoint [Client Browser for SharePoint 2010 and 2013](http://spcb.codeplex.com/) with each activation/deactivation so I know it is attaching properly.

Are there any special configurations necessary for it to work on SPOnline?  Thanks